# How to synchronize hamster-tracker with ubuntu one

Tags: ubuntu-one

I'm using hamster-tracker on different machines, so, I want to share my data across these.
How can I achieve, that hamster is using one single database, which is synced via ubuntu one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could add `~/.local/share/hamster-applet/` to your list of Cloud Folders syncing with Ubuntu One. You can do that by right-clicking on the folder > Ubuntu One > Syncronize This Folder.

Another option might be to move the `~/.local/share/hamster-applet/` folder into your `~/Ubuntu One` folder and put a symlink at `~/.local/share/hamster-applet/` pointing to the folder in your Ubuntu One directory. You can easily make a Link by right-clicking and selecting Make Link.

**NOTE:** One thing you can not do is put a symlink in the Ubuntu One folder pointing at `~/.local/share/hamster-applet/`. Ubuntu One will not follow a symlink.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this solution. The problem is that both my computers are running, therefore the hamster service is run twice. My home computer can only see the tasks track on my office computer three days ago, which is probably when I restarted there for the last time. It may be that the database is written only when the program is terminated and not continuously as it is running, or UbOne does not detect that  
I would even be willing to shut hamster at my work computer down, before starting it at home. The problem then is that there is no obvious way to terminate the hamster service.

Comment: Synchronisation was messed out, because a conflict was created. As a result I lost the data of one week.